# MATLAB: Plotting Two Equations: Conversion to double from struct is not possible

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB and I'm having problems plotting these two equations.  I'm trying to solve for a and c:

```
j = sym('2*(X*1/a)-((X)^2*1/a)+1/a')
k = sym('2*(1-X*1/a)-((1-X)^2*1/a)+c')

sol = solve(j,'a',k,'c');
```

Then I get "Conversion to double from struct is not possible.":

```
plot(sol,'a')
```

I also tried:

```
plot(sol,'a','c') (Not enough input arguments)
plot(sol,sol.a,sol.c) (Conversion to double from struct is not possible.)
```

Comment: MATLAB's initial purpose is for numerical math even though MathWorks bought MuPAD a few years ago in order to have it's own symbolic computation engine. Have a look at MuPAD or read the doc for [solve](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/toolbox/symbolic/solve.html) and try to follow the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try your code, I get the following answer:

```
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.
```

Symbolic solutions can be found only for simple equations. I guess your problem is too hard to be solved analytically by matlab.